# How can I get the URL of the attribute onclick located in <li>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, puppeteer

This is web scrapping proyect using puppeteer.
I have multiples `li` html elements inside `ul` tag. I don't want to make the question longer so I only write one `li` tag, the others `li` are the same only change the parameter `productId` number that is contained in `document.location.href`
Of course when I click the li tag this navigate to the full url.

```
<ul class="performances_sub_group_container">
    <li onclick="
        document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163856&amp;productId=101397570845&amp;lang=es';" 
        aria-labelledby="event_code_M2
        dtm_M2
        venue_M2
        teams_M2
        availability_M2" 
        style="height: fit-content; cursor: pointer; display: flex;"
        data-opposing-team-id="783565623" 
        data-host-team-id="783565809" 
        class="
        resale_item
        add_keyboard_support
        performance
        available 
        performance_SPORTING_EVENT
        performance-1
        with_location" 
        data-venue-id="101395257340"
        id="101437163856">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the url from the `onclick` attribute locate in `li` tag

```
onclick="document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163856&amp;productId=101397570845&amp;lang=es';"
```

What I have so far is I can accesss to onclick attribute converting it to string with the following code

```
const getPartidos = await newPage.$$("ul.performances_group_container > li > ul > li.available")
                    
                    for (const partido of getPartidos) {
                        const urlPartidos = await newPage.evaluate((element) => {
                            return element.onclick.toString()
                        }, partido)
                        console.log(urlPartidos)
                    }
```

The result of `console.log(urlPartidos)` is:

```
function onclick(event) {
document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163899&productId=101397570845&lang=es';
}
function onclick(event) {
document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163910&productId=101397570845&lang=es';
}
function onclick(event) {
document.location.href = '/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163911&productId=101397570845&lang=es';
}
```

#### 1. How can I get the url from the onclick function?

#### 2. How can I save the url into an array of objects, where every object contain the url like this:

```
[
{
url:"https://example.com/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163899&productId=101397570845&lang=es
},
{
url:"https://example.com/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163910&productId=101397570845&lang=es
},
{
url:"https://example.com/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163911&productId=101397570845&lang=es
}
]
```

#### There is a way to get this final result?

Comment: so you want to get the URL inside all the ```li``` tag that includes an ```onclick``` attribute?

Comment: Yes, the attribute onclick show me a function. and I guess that function generate the full url. But I don't how get it... I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

I never used `Puppeteer`. I assume that the `element` variable is an istance of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

If so, try with

```
const output = []

for (const partido of getPartidos) {
  const urlPartidos = await newPage.evaluate((element) => {
    let attr = element.getAttribute('onclick')
    output.push({url: attr.split('\'')[1]})
  }, partido)
}

console.log(output)
```

The above solution should work.

Anyway, reading the [evaluate](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate) method documentation, it looks you don't need it at all. The code could by semplified as:

```
const getPartidos = await newPage.$$("ul.performances_group_container > li > ul > li.available")

const output = []

for (const partido of getPartidos) {
    let attr = partido.getAttribute('onclick')
    output.push({url: attr.split('\'')[1]})
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi, the first solution throw me the following error: `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: output is not defined` and the second solution throw: `TypeError: partido.getAttribute is not a function`, I was trying different alternatives around both solutions but with no luck.

Comment: For the first solution: did you declared and initialized the `output` variable? Look better at the first solution, just before the for loop there is the `const output = []` instruction.
For the second: I should take a look to your code, maybe you are missing something.

Comment: Yes, I declared the variable `output` just before the for loop. And I still have the error.

Comment: sorry but this is impossible. Please edit your question by adding the code you are triyng to execute. For now, focus on the first solution I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Finally after testing many alternatives. I found the way to access to the attribute `onclick`, for some reason that ignore getAttribute and attr methods doesnt work.
This is what I did:

```
let output = []
        for (const partido of getPartidos) {
             const urlPartidos = await newPage.evaluate((element) => {
             return element.onclick.toString().split("'")[1]
        }, partido)
        
        output.push(
            {
             url: "https://intl.tickets.com" + urlPartidos
            }
        )
    }
    console.log(output)
```

The output is exactly what I was looking for

```
[
  {
    url: 'https://intl.tickets.com/secured/selection/resale/item?performanceId=101437163858&productId=101397570845&lang=es'
  }
]
```

Thanks to @radar155 to gave some idea to make this works